# Missing import option for 3ds format in the GUI?

Tags: import, file-format, compatibility

I would like to import a .3ds model into Blender.

I looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jdAsx4d1EY), and [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?171175-3DS-Max-Files-in-Blender), both are very old and don't seem to apply to the version of Blender I am currently using (2.76).

I have tried the `FILE` > `IMPORT` command, which gave me this menu:

[image]

It seems weird that previous versions of Blender (as I suppose was the case because of the links above) would support 3ds and that the import function went away in later versions.
But I'm still new to this, so I might just be looking in the wrong menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to activate the 3DS import addon.
To do that:

1. Go to the user perferences window via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, or the File Menu --> User Preferences.
2. Go to the addons tab
3. Choose the Import-Export addons from the left vertical category list.
4. Find the "Import-Export: Autodesk 3DS format" row, then press on the checkbox on the right.
5. If you want this to be available every time you open blender, Click on the "Save User Preferences" below.

Or visually:
[image]

After you do this, you'll have the 3DS format available in the File --> Import menu.

Answer (score 0):

This is the step you can take to turn on the import feature for .3ds format

1. Go to user preferences.
2. Go to the Add-on tab.
3. Click on the import-export category.
4. Look for Autodesk 3DS Format.
5. Click on the checkbox to activate it.

You should now be able to import 3ds format.

[image]